# how to convert string into array of objects

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have this kind of string.

```
[
    {
        "uniqueID" : "com.product",
        "name" : "john doe",
        "price" : "15",
        "description" : "some description"
    },
    {
        "uniqueID" : "com.product1",
        "name" : "john doe",
        "price" : "15",
        "description" : "some descriptio"
    }
]
```

and i want to change this into array of objects. like

```
Array
(
 [0] => [
    {
        "uniqueID" : "com.product",
        "name" : "john doe",
        "price" : "15",
        "description" : "some descriptio"
    },

    [1] => 
    {
        "uniqueID" : "com.product1",
        "name" : "john doe",
        "price" : "15",
        "description" : "some description"
    },
]
)
```

how i can do this, i used this code

```
  $data = $this->input->post('productArray');
  $dataArray = explode('},' , $data);
```

but it has give me this kind of solution. which is not as my requirement.

```
Array
(
    [0] => [
    {
        "uniqueID" : "com.product",
        "name" : "john doe",
        "price" : "15",
        "description" : "some description"

    [1] => 
    {
        "uniqueID" : "com.product1",
        "name" : "john doe",
        "price" : "15",
        "description" : "some description"
    }
]
)
```

it will be honor for me if you help me in this.

Comment: [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode). It's a JSON string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json_decode` is the thing you are looking for. It is a built-in PHP function. Here is the sample code listed below using your json string as input:

```
$string = '[{"uniqueID":"com.product","name":"john doe","price":"15","description":"some description"},{"uniqueID":"com.product1","name":"john doe","price":"15","description":"some descriptio"}]';

$array = json_decode($string);

print_r($array);
```

//Output///

> Array([   0 ]=>stdClassObject([   uniqueID ]=>com.product[   name
>   ]=>johndoe[   price ]=>15[   description ]=>somedescription)[   1
>   ]=>stdClassObject([   uniqueID ]=>com.product1[   name ]=>johndoe[
>   price ]=>15[   description ]=>somedescriptio))